# sharepoint Image gallery application with lighbox

Tags: javascript, caml-query

I want to create Image gallery widget in my sharepoint website that will access the image from sharepoint list.Below is my requirement

1. Image gallery view will display in carousel or slider
2. when we click on image the lightbox will appear
3. Please help in building javscript and caml query building and provide me the source code for photo gallery with slider

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for your requirements:

1. Create one Picture Library App in your site.
2. Create a new page.
3. Use [Bootstrap carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) in your html code.
4. Add Content editor on your page and give path to the newly created HTML file.
5. Fetch Pictures from picture library using SharePoint REST as given, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af1dc892-cc05-486d-90d6-4758aac0cc97/how-to-get-the-image-url-from-picture-library-folders-in-sharepoint).
6. Use these pictures to show on your page.